# How final constant class with no instances is better than constant interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, constants

While reading about constant interface antipattern, i found final constant class with no instances is better than constant interface.
Please explain me how?

```
public interface ConstIfc {
  public static final int constValue = 10;
}

public final class ConstClass {
  private ConstClass{}
  public static final int constValue = 10;
}
```

If constValue has to be used in a UtilClass without naming of Ifc/Class name we can implement/extends those.  but implements supports multiple inheritance. So how extends better?

Note: I'm able to understand static import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are an abstraction, and to remain abstract, they should not contain implementation details (including constant variables.) Interfaces also are often used to describe a public API, in which implementation details do not belong. For this reason it makes sense to put constant data into a class, rather than an interface.

I'm not sure what you mean by *"how extends better?"*, but I think you should avoid inheriting / extending this sort of implementation detail into multiple classes. Improperly leveraging implementation inheritance often leads to inflexible design. In your example, the `final` keyword on `ConstClass` utilizes the compiler to prevent you from doing this, which is not possible with an interface.

Answer (score 7):

I think the argument is that you don't need to extend OR implement a constant class or interface, now that we have static imports.  So if you're going to use static imports, having a class for your constants better fits the idea of what a class actually is, versus what an interface is.  And making it a final class removes the temptation to apply the anti-pattern; that is, to extend or implement the type that defines the constants.

In practice though, I don't think it makes too much difference which pattern you use.

Comment: Great! Thanks. So final class is better than constant interface in terms of static import and by avoiding inheriting all the constants. rit?

Comment: Since static fields objects are created at class level(and common to all objects), Is it static import on particular fields and inheriting(using implements) all the fields will create same amount of memory?

Comment: For Example In this below propgram how many MyOwn objects are created? `code`   
    class MyOwn{}
    public interface ConstantIfc { 
    public final static MyOwn REF = new MyOwn(); } class A implements ConstantIfc {} class B implements ConstantIfc {} public class c { public static void main(String... arg) { A refA = new A(); B refB = new B(); } }

Comment: Just one, because it's static in ConstantIfc.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of classes/interfaces with constants. It is much more flexible, powerful and robust choice.

Comment: Yes, but not always the best.  For example, DAYS_IN_WEEK or PI or any number of other true constants seem best described by a plain ole int.